# Параллельно отрисовывать графики функций в потоках C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, диаграммы

Задание: Параллельно отрисовывать графики функций: ax2+bx+c и x+b. При выполнении использовать потоки.
Есть форма с двумя chart и кнопками, при нажатии на которые рисуются графики. Потоки используются, потому что отрисовка идет одновременно.
Пытаюсь реализовать рисование графиков на форме в отдельных потоках, выдается System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'chart1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан." Пытаюсь через Invoke, но не выходит
Вот код

```
private void KnopOchka_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //chart1.Invoke(new ThreadStart(LineChart));
           // chart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { LineChart(); });
            chart1.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate { LineChart(); });
            Thread firstThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LineChart));
            firstThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread secondThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ParabolaChart));
            chart2.Invoke(new ThreadStart(ParabolaChart));
            chart2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ParabolaChart(); });
            secondThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        public void LineChart()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Line(i, 2));
            }
        }

        double Line(double x, double b)
        {
            return x + b;
        }

        double Parabola(double x)
        {
            return 2 * Math.Pow(x, 2) + 1 * x + 3;
        }

        void ParabolaChart()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Parabola(i));
            }
        }
```

С потоками первый раз работаю, не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: У вас задержка в целую секунду, это очень большой интервал, зачем вам вообще тут потоки? Возьмите System.Windows.Forms.Timer, настройте ему интервал тика в ту же самую одну секунду или даже меньше и рисуйте обе линии в одном потоке: сначала считаете обе точки, потом выводите в соответствующие области. Там не так долго все это происходит, чтобы было заметно на глаз. Если заметно, можно использовать перед обновлением изображения SuspendLayout и ResumeLayout после обновления

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke, когда вы пытаетесь использовать для записи объекты, принадлежащие форме, из другого потока. Необходимый класс находится в библиотеке WindowsBase.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate { LineChart(); });
        Thread firstThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LineChart));
        firstThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread secondThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ParabolaChart));
        chart2.Invoke(new ThreadStart(ParabolaChart));
        chart2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ParabolaChart(); });
        secondThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public void LineChart()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action<Form1>((sender) => { chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Line(i, 2)); }),
                new object[] { this });
        }
    }

    double Line(double x, double b)
    {
        return x + b;
    }

    double Parabola(double x)
    {
        return 2 * Math.Pow(x, 2) + 1 * x + 3;
    }

    void ParabolaChart()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action<Form1>((sender) => { chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Parabola(i)); }),
                new object[] { this });
        }
    }
```